# How do I apply CSS if an element *doesn't* have a certain class?

Tags: html, css, web-applications

I have a series of divs within a div. And I want to apply a css rule to all of them, and then another css rule to one of them using classes. Here is my current style:

```
.singleTiddler div { display:none; }
.singleTiddler div.singleTiddlervisible { display:block; }
```

The problem with Chrome is that it shows as using display:block in the inspector, but nothing shows up. The funny thing is that when I hover over it in the inspector, it is there but it has no height.

```
<div id="tiddlerDisplay" class="singleTiddler">
    <div class="singleTiddlervisible">
        <div>Hi</div><div>There</div><div>We</div>
        <div>Like</div><div>Divs</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>Hi</div><div>There</div><div>We</div>
        <div>Like</div><div>Divs</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div>Hi</div><div>There</div><div>We</div>
        <div>Like</div><div>Divs</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: u are soo fast dude in replying...isn't it?...

Comment: No. There is a checkbox on the question form that gives you this option. In the faq it is explicitly encouraged. I was typing my question when I found the answer, so I just answered it too. Hopefully someone will find it useful.

Comment: Strange, the answer is you acting like someone else?

Comment: No, that is how you do it. I am answering a question explaining, not what I do, but what you can do.

Comment: Downvoters: asking then answering your own question is fine. Please vote based on the merits of the actual content.

Comment: Need to see your HTML (this is just for clarifying the question; I know you've self-answered but your question needs a little more context as well). Also, unrelated to your answer: you can select an element that doesn't have a certain class by using `div:not(.singleTiddlervisible)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One major problem is that `.singleTiddler div` will apply to all divs at all levels. If there are divs underneath they will also be hidden. The override css will only apply to divs with the class `singleTiddlervisible`, thus only showing the root div. Use the child selector instead:

```
.singleTiddler > div { display:none; }
.singleTiddler > div.singleTiddlervisible { display:block; }
```

Comment: Why did you answer your own question seconds after you asked it?

Comment: There is a checkbox for it on the question form.

Comment: Is the third-person language necessary? It makes it sound as if this was posted from an alternate account and merged later (which actually has happened a fair number of times on the site).

Comment: I don't know. I could maybe, but that doesn't quite seem like a Q&A. I personally think that it improves the site overall to say what you can do, as opposed to what I did.

Comment: Actually, I do see your point. I should word it more neutral (more or less) which is probably what you meant.